# Is it possible for Tesseract to show a recognition percent for a character?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using Tesseract for recognizing custom symbols (more like pictographs, not numbers or letters). I need this for implementing a "spell-casting" mechanic in an Android game where you have to draw a symbol to cast a spell. I trained Tesseract on my symbol sheet and it recognizes the symbols just fine, but it also recognizes gibberish images as symbols. Obviously, I don't want this to happen, as it defeats the purpose of drawing a specific symbol. Does Tesseract have an option to display something like a recognition percent for a symbol?

Answer (score 1):

The "recognition percent" is called "confidence level" in Tesseract, and can be accessed by the tsv output option. More in detail in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66899977/15523359