# Pictograph or symbol recognition in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, neural-network, ocr, game-development

I am making an Android game the core mechanic of which is "spell-casting" by drawing previously specified symbols. I tried Tesseract for this, but it recognizes gibberish as symbols and does not have any way (that I know of) to gauge similarity to any of the symbols. What neural net/ocr utility could I use for my task?

Comment: Please upload your image and your code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out what I needed was the confidence score. I used Tesseract from the command line so far. TSV output option does the job:

```
tesseract test.png stdout --psm 10 tsv
```

From all the information of the output, the attention should be paid to the two last columns in the bottom string. One of the symbols I used is a spiral, so here is the:
[spiral itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjn4w.png) and the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4beq.png).
Tesseract recognized it as a spiral, which is coded as S and the confidence level is 83, which is pretty nice.

When I use a [gibberish picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jJLA.png), on the other hand, the
[output for gibberish picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB9KX.png) still shows it's an S, but now the confidence score is 19. Now it's pretty easy to filter out invalid input.